# Referencing resources directory from project object model variables

Tags: maven

If I can use `${project.build.sourceDirectory}` to reference the source directory, what do I use to reference the "resources" directory?

Looking at the super pom, it would seem that `${project.build.resources.resource.directory}` would work, but it does not . . .

Answer (score 62, accepted):

```
${project.build.resources[0].directory}
```

[maven reference @ Sonatype, chapter 'resource filtering'](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/resource-filtering-sect-properties.html) says that anything from maven internal "Model.class" can be accessed. quote :

> "*For a full list of properties available on the Maven Model object, take a look at the JavaDoc for the maven-model project here http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.0.4/maven-model/apidocs/index.html. Once you load this JavaDoc, take a look at the Model class. From this Model class JavaDoc, you should be able to navigate to the POM property you wish to reference.*"

Then, [maven help plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-help-plugin) has a handy [help:evaluate](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-help-plugin/evaluate-mojo.html) goal that let you do trial&error to discover the properties.

Comment: Not sure using "[0]" is a good idea, if for some reason the ordering changes, what once worked for you, will no longer work.

Comment: This will not work with antrun plugin and probably other plugins as well

Comment: This does not work inside a <fileSet /> element in a [maven-assembly-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/) descriptor.

Comment: Confirming that this (still) does not work at  maven-assembly-plugin descriptor

Comment: Today it is `${project.resources[0].directory}}$`, isn't it a typo or not?

Comment: Upvoted for that really usefull help:evaluate reference

Comment: I don't think this is a good practice. Sharing my implementation experience: Eclipse throws an error:
**Project build error: Resolving expression: '${project.build.resources[0].directory}': Detected the following recursive expression cycle in 'project.build.resources[0].directory': [build.resources[0].directory]**

Answer (score 50):

From [here](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Resources):

> **directory**: This element's value defines where the resources are to be found. 
>   The default directory for a build is `${basedir}/src/main/resources`.

Edit: for clarity

Comment: Thanks for the help, but this is not what I'm asking.  I understand how the resources are pulled into the build, and how to configure them.  I need to know how to reference this location via the pom properties as exposed through the ${xxx} notation.

Comment: Did you scroll in my comment?  The resources folder is referenced by this ${xxx} expression:  ${basedir}/src/main/resources

Comment: Yeah, I saw that.  I guess I was just expecting there to be a maven property for it . . . in particular, the docs say that you can access any element of the pom just by following the element names, which is how I derived the project.build.resources.resource.directory . . . but it doesn't work I guess.  Which leads me to wonder whether what I'm doing is non-standard; I try to avoid the non-standard, when doing maven stuff, like the plague ;)

Comment: It's more like they have a few convenience properties for stuff you use alot (${project.version} for example), but then other stuff you have to build based on ${basedir}.  So it's hard to say if what you're doing is non-standard.  The maven-resources-plugin does provide ways to perform operations on the resources if that's what you're trying to do though.

Comment: On windows the above suggestion results in a weird mixture of File separators.

Comment: [The book](https://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/resource-filtering-sect-properties.html) says: "If you are ever trying to reference output directories in Maven, you should never use a literal value like `target/classes`."  Probably for the reason mentioned by @MarkMcLaren.

Comment: should use ${project.basedir} to be idiomatic.

Comment: `${project.basedir}` represents the directory containing pom.xml (**deprecated**: `${basedir}`)

Answer (score 5):

Extending @chiebaud's answer, using the maven help plugin, I think the correct option today is

```
${project.resources[0].directory}
```

(without the "`.build`" part).