# how to run java application with environment variables loading from file?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I'm building java (`jdk 8`) application.

I want to run the application (run/debug mode) from my IDE (`Intellij IDEA`).

My application use some environment variables.

I know I can add the environment variables one by one in the Run/Debug configurations -> environment variables.

- Is it possible to load all those  environment variables from file (i.e env.list file) ?
- How can I tell the IDE to load the environment variables from file when running the application in Run/Debug mode ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now there is no choice like that in IDEs.
We have to manually feed all those stuffs in the Run/Debug configuration.
If you want you can add it as part of your gradle / maven from there you can do all those expected functionalitites and configure that task in the Run/Debug configuration.
That only will solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

There is no direct way to do this.

The only things that comes to my mind is:

- I don't know the version of your IDEA but there are plugins for that like this one, [EnvFile](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7861-envfile). But the format of these files are limited.

If you don't want to use it from directly from IDE you can code:

- Use can tinker with your build tool, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48693420/maven-read-environment-variable-in-properties-file/48802313) with Maven.
- Use can use [properties](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/properties.html). There is an [example](https://mkyong.com/java/java-properties-file-examples/).