# Maven Compile cant find src/main/resources directory

Tags: java, maven-3, maven-plugin, maven-surefire-plugin

I am trying to setup an integration-test environment using Maven for my project but am getting the below error when I run the Compile goal.

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:3.0.2:resources
>   (default-resources) on project mavenintegrationtest: Error loading
>   property file
>   '/Users/xxx/dev/poc/java/mavenintegrationtest/profiles/dev/config.properties'
>   -> [Help 1]

The error seems to be complaining that it cant find the config.properties file in that location which is correct. For some reason it has removed the "src/main/resources" bit from the file path.

So the correct full path is,

`/Users/xxx/dev/poc/java/mavenintegrationtest/src/main/resources/profiles/dev/config.properties`

but for some reason its removed src/main/resources and so is looking in,

`/Users/xxx/dev/poc/java/mavenintegrationtest/profiles/dev/config.properties`

Does anyone know whats causing this ?

My POM is as shown below and I get this error when I uncomment the following "filter" tag,

`<filter>${basedir}/profiles/${build.profile.id}/config.properties</filter>`

I've tried removing the ${basedir} statement and still get the same error.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.stackoverflow</groupId>
  <artifactId>mavenintegrationtest</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <name>mavenintegrationtest</name>
  <url>http://www.example.com</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <filters>
      <filter>${basedir}/profiles/${build.profile.id}/config.properties</filter>
    </filters>

    <resources>
      <resource>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
        <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
      </resource>
    </resources>

  </build>
  <!-- Profile configuration -->
  <profiles>
    <!-- The configuration of the development profile -->
    <profile>
      <id>dev</id>
      <!-- The development profile is active by default -->
      <activation>
        <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
      </activation>
      <properties>
        <build.profile.id>dev</build.profile.id>
      </properties>
    </profile>
    <!-- The configuration of the integration-test profile -->
    <profile>
      <id>integration-test</id>
      <properties>
        <build.profile.id>integration-test</build.profile.id>
      </properties>
    </profile>
  </profiles>

</project>
```

[image]

Comment: When you say you removed the ${basedir} part, I guess you also removed the leading / and left only “src/main/resources”?

Comment: don't you have more information regarding the error message?

Comment: @Sxilderik yes that's correct, i've tried running just with "src/main/resources'

Comment: @lpinto.eu I've tried switching on debug trace and then get a "FileNotFound" exception message which is clear - it cant find my config.properties file because its removed the "src/main/resources" bit from the path....I dont understand what's causing this.

Comment: [Possibly relevant.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9216557/referencing-resources-directory-from-project-object-model-variables)

Comment: There is no profiles folder in your root project. And though maven is expecting one since you specified it in the filters section.

Comment: @Sxilderik thanks - are you suggesting that I move my profiles/ directory to the project root ? I was hoping to avoid that as it didnt seem the right approach - is that correct approach ? In the resources section I specified the resources location but for some reason its not picking this up.

Comment: @robbie70, yes you should move the folder and that's the correct approach. See the update in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `filter` ([link](https://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-filtering/)) element will parse your files and apply a content filter on them.
The `profiles` ([link](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html)) element helps you define different environments for the build.

All of this as to do with your resources. These can be configuration files, or other type of files. If you filter then you can change the content of this files with other values - e.g. pom properties. When using profiles you can have different replacement properties for each environment.

You should move the profiles up in the tree for the default path, or add a configuration in your pom for the resource location.
The `base dir` is the folder containing your pom. You should have your profile folder here.

[image: My own example]

Also, [here](http://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/tips-and-tricks/creating-profile-specific-configuration-files-with-maven/) is some good information about profiles and its configurations.

Comment: @Ipinto.eu thank you - I will check this. That link you posted is the one that I have been following ! :)

Comment: The same I used. Just move the profiles folder as I show in my project print. If it helped please fell free to vote my answer and or accept it.

Comment: @Ipinto.eu thank you that worked ! :) interestingly I also got my original version working by adding src/main/resources to my filter tag as follows,
 <filter>${basedir}/src/main/resources/profiles/${build.profile.id}/config.properties</filter>

but from what you're saying the standard approach is to have "profiles" directory off the main project directory and not in the resources directory - in which case I am not clear what effect the resources tag has ?
I will accept your answer as the answer.

Comment: the resources are non source code files, that you want to add to your project - e.g. configurations, translations... the profiles you will use to "customize" the resources, and so, just to distinguish this, you store them in a different location.