# Maven: Overview for the values of Maven properties

Tags: maven-3, maven-plugin

I would like to find out the values of *all* Maven properties as they apply to some Maven project.
`mvn help:system` lists OS environment variables and JVM system properties, but no Maven properties.
`mvn help:evaluate` only works in an interactive mode, that means I have to type a single Maven property, (e.g. `${project.build.outputDirectory}`) to get the value of that property.

I'm looking for a way get a full list of all Maven properties and their values.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4532687/367285) related question and answer is helpful.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where is the list of predefined Maven properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4409560/where-is-the-list-of-predefined-maven-properties)

Answer (score 67, accepted):

As a workaround, add this to the `<plugins> ... </plugins>` section inside your project's `pom.xml`:

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.7</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <phase>validate</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>run</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <tasks>
          <echoproperties />
        </tasks>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Now execute `mvn validate`.
On the console, prefixed with `[echoproperties]`, there will be the full list of system properties, including those set by Maven such as `project.build.outputDirectory`, `basedir`, and `settings.localRepository`.

Comment: Nice idea, but it does not list all properties, for example it does not list `${project.build.scriptSourceDirectory}`

Comment: Nice try, but here's another it doesn't pick up: `session.executionRootDirectory`.

Answer (score 31):

the maven-help-plugin does what you want, just call it with `-Dexpression=project.properties` this will print the properties tag of the effective pom.

```
mvn help:evaluate -Dexpression=project.properties
```

Bonus Points when you just want the properties output and not the maven output

```
mvn help:evaluate -Dexpression=project.properties -q -DforceStdout
```

or with the explicit version because `-DforceStdout` works since version 3.1.0

```
mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-help-plugin:3.1.0:evaluate -Dexpression=project.properties -q -DforceStdout
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer IMO. It doesn't require any edits to pom files and can be used to view any property e.g. `-Dexpression=spring.version`

Comment: If you are using an old maven version (for example 3.3.9) specify plugin version 3.1.0 to avoid the error described in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55736016/how-to-fix-java-lang-classnotfoundexception-org-apache-maven-model-io-xpp3-mav

Comment: This only includes properties defined in the `pom.xml`, but not programmatically computed ones such as those defined by the `bsh-property` goal of the `build-helper-maven-plugin`.

Answer (score 7):

Not sure if helps, but I found this when trying to do the same thing:

```
mvn com.github.ekryd.echo-maven-plugin:echo-maven-plugin:echo -Decho.message='${project.build.testOutputDirectory}'
```

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15763915/how-to-echo-in-maven-without-antrun-plugin).

Adding the following to `${user.home}/.m2/settings.xml`:

```
  <pluginGroups>
    <pluginGroup>com.github.ekryd.echo-maven-plugin</pluginGroup>
  </pluginGroups>
```

the command can be shortened to:

```
mvn echo:echo -Decho.message='${project.build.testOutputDirectory}'
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to get them "officially", but here is a workaround. Add `maven-antrun-plugin` to your project and run `mvn test -X`. The plugin will show all properties passed to it from Maven. The list looks complete to me.

Comment: So I followed your suggestion, but it didn't work; added maven-antrun-plugin in the pom.xml as pointed out in [its documentation](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVENUSER/Antrun+Plugin), then i executed `mvn test -X`. I couldn't find any Maven-specific properties. Yegor, does your list include the Maven property `project.build.outputDirectory`?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using the below, which lists not just the properties defined in the `pom.xml`, but also the ones defined programmatically by other plugins:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>list-properties</id>
            <!-- Binds to the "validate" phase by default. -->
            <goals>
                <goal>bsh-property</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <source>
                    for (Map.Entry entry : project.getProperties().entrySet())  {
                        log.info(entry.getKey() + " = " + entry.getValue());
                    }
                </source>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

I imagine it's similar to the `echoproperties` solution, but it is "more powerful" than the `mvn help:evaluate` solution.

Comment: This works perfectly, and includes generated properties (for anything run prior to it).  Running it in the `install` phase and listing it after all other plugins should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Actually project.build.outputDirectory is there but you need to execute in 'compile' phase, and NOT in 'validate'. I guess what properties are available also depends on the current phase for the executing goal of a particular plug-in, in this case 'maven-antrun-plugin'.

```
            <!-- Ant Run Plugin for debugging pom.xml and calling ant tasks -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${ant.plugin.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <tasks>
                            <echoproperties/>
                        </tasks>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Answer (score -4):

Had the same issue. Changed the timeout and maxheap in findbugs configuration through maven.

The below fixed it for me :

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>findbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <maxHeap>2048</maxHeap>
                <timeout>1800000</timeout>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: This is completed unrelated to the question; there is nothing to "fix" and OP is not using Findbugs.  They're trying to print Maven properties, which Findbugs does not do, and those settings are completely unrelated.