# How to echo in Maven without Antrun plugin?

Tags: maven, logging, maven-antrun-plugin

How can I print to the console while executing a mvn command (in a phase/goal), but not using Maven Antrun plugin?

Why I reject Antrun solutions:

- The overhead in code to print a single message is massiv.
- The output is no formated like maven output
- I cannot attach a severity to the message (e.g. DEBUG, INFO, ERROR, etc)

Currently an Ant-echo looks like this (see line with "hello world"):

```
[INFO] --- maven-antrun-plugin:1.7:run (default) @ ejpd-alertmanager-ear ---
[WARNING] Parameter tasks is deprecated, use target instead
[INFO] Executing tasks
main:
 [echo] hello world
[INFO] Executed tasks
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

However, I expect it to look like this (see line with "hello world").

```
[INFO] --- maven-antrun-plugin:1.7:run (default) @ ejpd-alertmanager-ear ---
[WARNING] Parameter tasks is deprecated, use target instead
[INFO] Executing tasks
[INFO] hello world
[INFO] Executed tasks
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I'm positive, I am missing something here, since I cannot be the first to raise this demand. Thank you for any smart hint.

Comment: What exactly do you want to print out? The output will already contain details of the phase/goal that is being executed.

Comment: Hi Dave, 1st) property values when a goal has been executed (I want to check if a variable is set correctly at runtime. e.g. operting system, concatenated properties when running the maven-resources-plugin. etc.). 2) When executing antrun copy or move task (or again the maven-resources-plugin), I want to echo in a maven-formated-style. Saying, starting with [INFO]. e.g. [INFO] Successfully copied file x to path y. Do I make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tried this myself but there is a plugin here which may help:

http://code.google.com/p/maven-echo-plugin/

Comment: Unfortunately this plugin is not in Maven Central.

Comment: A quick check on google shows it is available from mvn repository at this link: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.soebes.maven.plugins/maven-echo-plugin - ok, it's not exactly the same as I originally answered but it looks to do the same task.

Comment: Probably that is all we can get for now. Thanks.

Comment: I have written that the plugin from code.google.com is not available in Maven central where the given plugin (groupId: com.soebes.maven.plugins) is available from maven central.

Comment: Try the 'echo-maven-plugin' available in Maven Central: https://code.google.com/p/echo-maven-plugin/

Answer (score 5):

You should try the [Maven Echo plugin](http://khmarbaise.github.com/Maven-Echo-Plugin/):

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>com.soebes.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-echo-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>0.1</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <phase>initialize</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>echo</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
  <configuration>
    <echos>
      <echo>This is the Text which will be printed out.</echo>
    </echos>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Or furthermore take a deeper look into the [integration test of the plugin.](https://github.com/khmarbaise/Maven-Echo-Plugin/blob/master/src/it/basicTest/pom.xml)

which is available via Maven Central. BTW: If you have further requests/improvements just file [in an issue](https://github.com/khmarbaise/Maven-Echo-Plugin/).

Answer (score 5):

You can use [Björn Ekryd](https://github.com/Ekryd)'s [Echo Maven Plugin](https://github.com/Ekryd/echo-maven-plugin), which is published in [Maven Central](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccom.github.ekryd.echo-maven-plugin%7Cecho-maven-plugin%7C1.2.0%7Cmaven-plugin).

It has a normal amount of XML required for a Maven plugin, the output is formatted like the other Maven log lines, and you can assign a severity level to your message (default is INFO).

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.github.ekryd.echo-maven-plugin</groupId>
    <artifactId>echo-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>echo</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <message>war has changed</message>
                <level>INFO</level>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

---

```
[INFO] --- maven-war-plugin:2.4:war (default-war) @ mymodule ---
[INFO] Packaging webapp
[INFO] Processing war project
[INFO]
[INFO] --- echo-maven-plugin:1.2.0:echo (default) @ mymodule ---
[INFO] war has changed
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Also, this plugin has [95% code coverage](https://coveralls.io/github/Ekryd/echo-maven-plugin), which is pretty cool.

Comment: Cool, especially that I can use `<fromFile>` to output the content of a file. Just perfect for my needs! This should be the accepted answer as of today.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Groovy Maven Plugin](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/GMAVEN/Home) for this.

```
<plugin>                                                         
    <groupId>org.codehaus.gmaven</groupId>                       
    <artifactId>groovy-maven-plugin</artifactId>                 
    <version>2.0</version>                                       
    <executions>                                                 
        <execution>                                              
            <phase>validate</phase>                              
            <goals>                                              
                <goal>execute</goal>                             
            </goals>                                             
            <configuration>                                      
                <source>                                         
                    log.info('Test message: {}', 'Hello, World!')
                </source>                                        
            </configuration>                                     
        </execution>                                             
    </executions>                                                
</plugin>
```

The configuration above will produce the following output:

```
[INFO] Test message: Hello, World!
```