# How to use data in *.properties at jooq-codegen-plugin in pom.xml?

Tags: spring-boot, maven, pom.xml, jooq, jooq-codegen-maven

I want to use Data in *.properties...

This is my application.properties file

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postrgresql://host:port/dbName 
spring.datasource.username=username
spring.datasource.password=password
```

and my "jooq-codegen-plugin" in <build> in pom.xml

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
            <artifactId>jooq-codegen-maven</artifactId>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
                    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
                    <version>42.2.23</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <configuration>
                <jdbc>
                    <driver>org.postgresql.Driver</driver>
                    <user>${spring.datasource.username}</user>
                    <password>${spring.datasource.password}</password>
                    <url>${spring.datasource.url}</url>
                </jdbc>
                <generator>
                    <database>
                        <name>org.jooq.meta.postgres.PostgresDatabase</name>
                        <includes>.*</includes>

                        <inputSchema>public</inputSchema>
                    </database>
                    <target>
                        <packageName>com.wavers.hwacha.generated.jooq</packageName>
                        <directory>src/main/java/</directory>
                    </target>
                </generator>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

and Part of Error when I run [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2F9t0.png)

```
[INFO] Database parameters      
[INFO] ----------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]   dialect                : POSTGRES
[INFO]   URL                    :
```

and another error message

```
Cannot execute query. No Connection configured
```

I guess that url info written at pom.xml do not map...

I Can't find any way... help me

Answer (score 0):

This is mostly a question of how to read properties into a `pom.xml` *in general*. One option is this one:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>initialize</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>read-project-properties</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <files>
                    <file>src/main/resources/application.properties</file>
                </files>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Thanks! but i try to the way, it do not read parameter in application.properties..

Comment: @beginOfBegin: I don't know what you tried *specifically*, but this is one way how you can read properties and use them in your `pom.xml`. You can use the [`maven-echo-plugin` or `groovy-maven-plugin` to print out  your properties for debugging purposes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15764995/521799)