# How can i see my document settings.xml (maven)

Tags: maven, archiva

I'm trying to see my informations (username & url) in settings.xml but there is no document in my folder .m2, I try to display it with ls -la but nothing to do. How can we get those informations?

Comment: Whats the directory path of your maven installation?  it could be within the conf folder of the installation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maven will not automatically create the user settings.xml if it does not exist. If there are any settings you want to configure with non-default values, you'll have to create it yourself based on the examples in https://maven.apache.org/settings.html.

If you want to see the current values which Maven uses see here: [Maven: Overview for the values of Maven properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12317609/maven-overview-for-the-values-of-maven-properties).