# How can i print the value of maven pre-defined variables directly inside pom file without using any third party plugin

Tags: maven

I am working on a maven project and i want to see what ${project.basedir} contains ! As per all documentation it should be root path in which my project resides but what i am getting is rootPath/doc !

what can be wrong here ?

Comment: Why do you want to avoid other plugins? A solution would be https://stackoverflow.com/q/12317609/927493

Comment: I was thinking if there is inbuilt functionality in maven itself to print or echo existing variables , there is no such way ?

Comment: In Maven, you cannot really do much without plugins. What is the problem in using a plugin? The build itself already uses a ton of plugins.

Comment: Ok thanks ! I will make use of plugin then !