# How to find all maven system properties

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-3

Does anybody know how to find all maven system properties?

If I do mvn --help, I can see

```
-D,--define <arg>                      Define a system property
```

But no way to find an exhaustive list of those properties on internet.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Sorry, I cannot really follow you. With `-D`, you can define any property you want, like `-Ddog=food` or `-Dxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx=yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy`. Whether they are used or not during the build depends on your POM and the plugins that you use.

Comment: Thank you for your response. The response below complets yours.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where is the list of predefined Maven properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4409560/where-is-the-list-of-predefined-maven-properties)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be great to have such a list, but the available / recognized properties are in the hands of plugin authors and there is no global registry. They may even change between plugin versions. However, they usually are part of the plugin documentation.

Some commonly used Maven properties:

- `maven.compiler.source`
- `maven.compiler.target`
- `maven.compiler.testSource`
- `maven.compiler.testTarget`
- `project.build.sourceEncoding`
- `project.reporting.outputEncoding`
- `maven.javadoc.skip`
- `maven.test.skip`

Furthermore, you can define your own property and use it anywhere in your pom.xml file via `${my.custom.property}`.

Links:

- https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#properties
- http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-source-and-target.html
- https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/encoding.html

Comment: There is another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12389296/1725096) that could reveal some more of the properties (implicitly) set in a given Maven project.